# A simple project shakes on the phone and works fine in the Editor with the same FPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-editor

Here 2 videos from Editor and from phone: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gs0Ik9EojhbbPUZh0lNmPigVHWpAjERi?usp=sharing

In the video from the phone, you can see how the planet is jerking up and down quickly (in fact, an arrow is jerking).

Here code for the arrow to face the center of the planet, for control and for move.

```
    private void Update()
    {
      body.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(body.transform.up, (body.transform.position - transform.position).normalized) * body.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, body.GetComponent<ArrowController>().Joystick.Horizontal  * 110 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
      if (Math.Abs((body.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude - body.OrbitRadius) > 0.01)
      {
        float shift = body.OrbitRadius - (body.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
        body.transform.position += body.transform.up * shift;
      }
      body.transform.position += body.transform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Why can this happen?

Comment: tbh you probably need to provide a [mcve] however the above code in some situations moves he body twice.. and the fact you move position not use some form of velocity or whatever does suggest it would move in a more jerky fashion

Comment: don't set the position, rotation of objects.  use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html or Transform.Rotate (or perhaps Transform.RotateAround)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added transform.Rotate() and transform.Translate() and it didn't help.
I don’t understand how it works and why the problem appears only on the phone, but I found a solution.

My code can be divided into 4 operations:

1. The rotation of the arrow relative to the center of the planet.
2. Turn of an arrow from pressing the player.
3. Correction of the
   distance from the center of the planet to the arrow.
4. The movement
   of the arrow along its own axis Z.

Initially, the code ran like this:
1 + 2 then
3 then
4

But I changed this to:
2 then
3 + 4 then
1

Now it’s not jerking. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't set the position, rotation of objects.

Use calls like [docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) or Transform.Rotate (or perhaps Transform.RotateAround)

Even better, just set the velocity or rotational velocity and allow the engine to do the work.